# Why does SQLAlchemy have data types in CAPS and some using normal casing?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

When intellisense was giving me options to autocomplete code, I noticed that almost every data type for Flask-SQLAlchemy had the type written in CAPS and regular casing. EX. `db.INTEGER` vs `db.Integer` or `db.VARCHAR` vs `db.Varchar`. What's the difference between the two types and why do they exist?

Comment: You can run a help(db.Integer) and help(db.INTEGER) and see if there is anything different about them.

Comment: From the documentation it can be seen that the other are [generic types](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/type_basics.html#generic-types), the other the [SQL standard / multiple vendor types](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/type_basics.html#sql-standard-and-multiple-vendor-types).